# JoinAcross Memory Leak

Tags: bugs, dataset, memory, debugging

I believe JoinAcross may have a memory leak but would appreciate some help looking at it. It appears to be small when used just once but when iterated a lot it eventually crashes my wolframscripts. I've tried Share[] and ClearSystemCache[] but they don't fix the issue. I've written the below toy example to show the leak:

```
SeedRandom[1234];
data1 = Table[<|"Date" -> DatePlus[Today, t],"Value" -> RandomReal[]|>, {t,1, 10000}];
data2 = Table[<|"Date" -> DatePlus[Today, t],"Value" -> RandomReal[]|>, {t,1, 10000}];
Do[
  memoryBefore = MemoryInUse[];
  data = JoinAcross[data1, data2, "Date", "Inner", KeyCollisionFunction -> ({"Data1" <> #, "Data2" <> #} &)];
  ClearAll[data];
  memoryAfter = MemoryInUse[];
  memoryChange = memoryAfter - memoryBefore;
  memoryInMegabytes = N[memoryChange/2^20];
  WriteLine[$Output, "Memory Change (MB): " <> ToString@memoryInMegabytes];
  ,
  {10}
];
```

This gives the output:

```
(*
Memory Change (MB): 7.17958
Memory Change (MB): 4.73375
Memory Change (MB): 4.73399
Memory Change (MB): 4.7343
Memory Change (MB): 4.7346
Memory Change (MB): 4.7346
Memory Change (MB): 4.7346
Memory Change (MB): 4.7346
Memory Change (MB): 4.7346
Memory Change (MB): 4.73454
*)
```

Thank you for any help!

Comment: See [How to report bugs?](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/a/192/9490).

Comment: `$HistoryLength = 0` will give some remedy. However, a small increase is still visible.

Comment: Yeah, I see that too. In my production scripts I've put ```$HistoryLength = 0``` and it gives me more time but still does eventually crash.

Comment: Anyway, I have reported the bug to Wolfram though I can't say for sure if it is indeed a bug.

Comment: Received this response from Wolfram:  It does appear that JoinAcross is not behaving properly. I have forwarded an issue report to our developers with the information you provided, and added your contact information to the report so that you can be notified when it is resolved.

Comment: @rfrasier did you receive any update from wolfram if it is resolved? They did release 13.2.1 with a lot of bug fixes, maybe this is fixed as well?

Comment: @user13892, yes I did finally receive an email from them that this bug has been fixed. I have some code to share and will answer my own question momentarily. Honestly, it's major bugs to core functions like this that don't get resolved for >1 year that make Mathematica a toy rather than a dependable language. I've moved on to Python like the rest of the world until Mathematica can find a way to make money while also open-sourcing their software. Sorry for the rant but it's just that this bug caused me some major difficulties at work...

Comment: @user13892, I just checked the code that WRI sent to me but I noticed that they weren't running my exact code and when I've tried the above code on the latest Mathematica version (13.3), I still get the exact same memory leaks. I give up!